# Appending to a div whilst adding css elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following script where i'm detecting for a word then replacing it, plus adding a new div, however i can't seem to add a long paragraph with line breaks. I've tried using paragraph and line break tags but can't seem to figure out how to append whilst also inserting css rules

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        /*var doc = document.getElementById('paymentMethod').innerHTML;
        var res = doc.replace("Account customers", "Payment pending");
     document.getElementById("paymentMethod").innerHTML = res;*/


     if(document.getElementById('paymentMethod').innerHTML === "Account customers "){
        var doc = document.getElementById('paymentMethod').innerHTML;
        var res = doc.replace("Account customers", "Payment pending");
           document.getElementById("paymentMethod").innerHTML = res;


         document.getElementById('element').append("Payment Options:Bank payment,Bank details Direct into the PayPal account:  the phone by card to any of our Sales Team .Thank you for your order!");
         console.log("inserted");

         var eley = document.getElementById('element');

         }

     else
         console.log("not inserted");



    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to append an element, like a paragraph, and add some styles using jQuery. ¿OK?

To do that, you can use two **jQuery methods**: `append()` and `css()`, chaining them, like this:

```
 $("#element").append("<p>Your paragraph text here</p>").css('color', 'red');
```

('color' is the name of the css rule, and 'red' is the value)

I think the issue is you are trying to use `append()` on a not jQuery element, when you do:

```
document.getElementById('element').append(..........)
```

`document.getElementById` is not jQuery, just vanilla js.

For more info, see: [jQuery append()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) and [jQuery css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Actually that works, i'm an idiot, thankyou very much